# How to create a session using Fastapi so when a user login we can use it's id for multipurpose. I mean we can fetch id from session only

Tags: python, fastapi

I want to create a session in fast API to get data from cookies.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you are asking. Please try to be specific in what you are trying to accomplish, show us what code you have, and describe what's not working as expected.

Comment: just tell me how to create session in fastapi to store data in cookie. so that whatever I am storing inside cookie I can use it.

Comment: `fast-sessions` lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API stops being API when you use sessions.
You can use JWT authentication in this case, not session.
Otherwise you'd best build websocket architecture.
See official FastAPI docs https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/